# Progress Bar Percent Calculation

Tags: vb6, progress-bar

I am new to VB6 and am working on some code for a business (cattle auction). They are wanting a progress to show on their main page the percent that is left in the sale. the progress bar would be based on (Total head remaining / total head checked In)

I have tried finding information on how to make this work in old forums and on Youtube but since VB6 is so old i'm not finding useful information.

All the videos I have watched and forums I have read show the progress bar moving based on a timer or button. I am needing it to move based on other information entered ( if that makes sense ).

Comment: There are specific controls to represent the progressbar itself. I'm pretty sure MSFT common controls included that.

Comment: Are you asking about the ProgressBar control, or do you intend to make your own from native elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 ProgressBar documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa443485(v%3dvs.60)

The ProgressBar is in the common controls library, so you'll need to select `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0` in the Toolbox Components list before it will be available in the Toolbox.

I prefer setting the Scrolling property to smooth scrolling.

Using it is easy, a simplest sample using your descriptions could have a HeadsToSell textbox, a StartAuction button, and a CowSold button. Clicking the StartAuction button sets the ProgressBar Max property to the number of heads, then for every head that is sold, clicking the CowSold button decrements the number of available head and updates the ProgressBar value.

```
Option Explicit

Private CurrentHeadCound As Integer

Private Sub CowSold_Click()
  CurrentHeadCound = CurrentHeadCound - 1
  ProgressBar1.Value = CurrentHeadCound
End Sub

Private Sub StartAuction_Click()

  ProgressBar1.Max = HeadsToSell.Text
  ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Max
  CurrentHeadCound = ProgressBar1.Max

End Sub
```